# Cannot see Http Callout in Flows

Tags: visual-workflow, callout, httprequest

To turn on Http callout in flows, at first I have made an external credential with authentication protocol as custom.
After that, I have made a named credential, enabled it for callouts, and use the previous external credential.

After that, I made a new permission set, assigned myself in the permission and added the created External Credential Principal access.

After this, when I go to the flows I don't see the HTTP Callout option in a new Action

Comment: The action should be available if you have the right edition and perms: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_http_callout.htm&type=5

Comment: I have added the permissions and given it to the user, but the option doesn't still pop up. I am using the professional edition. I also have lightning experience...

Comment: Professional edition isn't enough, read the doc.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Callout is Available in:
Lightning Experience
Enterprise, Unlimited, and Developer Editions.
In Flow Builder, dragging the Action Element on to the canvas exposes the Action modal. There, you should see the button at the bottom left of the modal: [image]

Comment: I have added all the permissions and using the professional edition. I have the lightning experience